# Ajax toolkit 2013 version errors

Tags: asp.net-ajax, webforms

I download the package whit ajax 4.5 version, I added the DDL to toolbox, reference to same DDL as a added items to toolbox, using this on aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

But this error occur, what did I do wrong?

```
Unhandled exception at line 3, column 412 in http://localhost:6944/View/Chart/Chart.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;AjaxControlToolkit,+Version=4.5.7.123,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:e669ce41-1aa1-4541-aae9-fa5dc37e70db:de1feab2:fcf0e993:f2c8e708:720a52bf:f9cec9bc:589eaa30:698129cf:fb9b4c57:ccb96cf9
```

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

All was added from toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create one WEB API, the project already has one AJAX version and give a lot of problems, I solve it creating one empty WebForms. Add ajaxtoolkit to tollbox and the correct DLL will be added automatically if any version was add, And be happy.